# Beautiful Soup: parsing table row data returns an error

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've tried a heap of different combinations of code to try and get the table data out of this table. Simply using `soup.table` doesn't return this specific table from the page, and I can't figure out why.

I've managed to find it by class by using `class_:'table assessment-item'` but when I try and parse individual rows or data, it throws an error.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.qut.edu.au/study/unit?unitCode=IFB104")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all(class_='table assessment-item')
table_data = table.find_all('td')
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/study/Desktop/QUT Final/demo.py", line 7, in <module>
table_data = table.find_all('td')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1807, in __getattr__
"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three tables returned having class as `'table assessment-item'`.

You just need to iterate over them:

```
table = soup.find_all(class_='table assessment-item')

table_data = [tbl.find_all('td') for tbl in table]

print table_data
```

Comment: I understand your answer, but I don't understand why I can't set three tables as one variable...

Comment: How can I break each loop into a new variable? (This is really the first time I've done Python, so is it something like): `for tbl in table:
 i++
 "tbl\i" = tbl.find_all('td')
 return "tbl\i"`

Comment: Nvm. Figured it out. `table[0], table[1], table[2]`